# Magento show and edit tracking number field in order overview

Tags: magento

does anyone know howto programmatically show and make the field editable for tracking number field in order overview?

I am thinking this.

**step 1.** First enable showing the tracking field in Grid.php, so extend ... Does anyone have an example how to add a column? (and for that matter hide an existing column)

Add this to /etc/config.xml under events so Magento knows what to call

```
<core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
    <observers>
    <SNH_ShipMailInvoice_Observer_addTrackingColumnToGrid>
        <type>model</type>
        <class>SNH_ShipMailInvoice_Model_Observer</class>
        <method>addTrackingColumnToGrid</method>
    </SNH_ShipMailInvoice_Observer_addTrackingColumnToGrid>
    </observers>
</core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
```

**step 2.a** Then populate the Grid with the tracking code if applicable

So first add a field in /Model/Observer.php (that answers step 1)

```
public function addTrackingColumnToGrid($observer)
{
// this will return the block name for every block triggered by the observer
$block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();

// filter - we only want the block for the sales order grid
if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_grid){
    // well, that was easy!
    $block->addColumn('tracking_number', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Tracking number'),
        'index' => 'tracking_number',
        'type' => 'input',
        'width' => '120px',
        'renderer' => 'SNH_ShipMailInvoice_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_addTrackingColumnToGrid'
    ));

}
}
```

**step 2.b** Then we need to populate the field with available tracking info

> 'renderer' =>
>   'SNH_ShipMailInvoice_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_addTrackingColumnToGrid'

should call to addTrackingColumnToGrid.php in /Block/Adminhtml/Renderer/addTrackingColumnToGrid.php

* CURRENT PROBLEM: ERROR **** 
This is where I am getting my white page no answer

**step 2.c** Lookup the tracking number per order in row. Currently untested/unconfirmed

```
// HOW DO I POPULATE VAR $order for each line? 
$shipmentCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_shipment_collection')->setOrderFilter($order)->load();

foreach ($shipmentCollection as $shipment){     
    // This will give me the shipment IncrementId, but not the actual tracking information.
    foreach($shipment->getAllTracks() as $tracknum) {
        $tracknums[]=$tracknum->getNumber(); }  
        // How to show the tracking information     
        // CODE HERE 
    }
}
```

**step 3** Then when I click on the dropdown option Masssaction (already programmed) the backend should process the selected items only and store the tracking ID to the shipment (that is created shortly after)

(and after that continue invoice and ship)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I may suggest something simpler:

1. Add a column that shows a tracking number.
2. If no tracking number exists, a link that says "Add tracking."
3. It tracking number exists, show the tracking number as a hyperlink. Also have an "Add tracking" link below it, for multiple tracking numbers per order.
4. Clicking the "Add tracking" link converts the link to a text field. Clicking the tracking number (if present), converts the tracking number to a text field prepopulated with the value of the tracking number (for editing).
5. Clicking away converts the text field(s) back to text links after saving. I do recommend a "loading" visual cue during the saving process.

**How to add a column to the Sales Order grid**

Setup an event observer. (You could use a rewrite in your config.xml file, but this can potentially cause conflicts with other modules.)

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
            <observers>
                <Namespace_Module_Observer_addTrackingColumnToGrid>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>Namespace_Module_Observer</class>
                    <method>addTrackingColumnToGrid</method>
                </Namespace_Module_Observer_addTrackingColumnToGrid>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Create your observer in `./app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model/Observer.php`. It should look something like this.

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function addTrackingColumnToGrid($observer)
    {
        // this will return the block name for every block triggered by the observer
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();

        // filter - we only want the block for the sales order grid
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_grid){

            // well, that was easy!
            $block->addColumn('tracking_number', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Tracking number')
            ));

        }
    }
}
```

Try looking in Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid for clues on how to use the `addColumn` method. It's pretty much universal for all Magento admin grids, which is nice. If you're looking to add custom functionality (besides just retrieving data), though, there's a pretty good chance you're going to need to figure out how to apply "renderers."

Once you've got that part figured out, you just need to setup an Ajax controller and drop in a little JavaScript to transmit the update information to your controller.

This is a pretty broad question, so I can't exactly do it all for you (without writing an extension), but I'll try to help you along the way.

For what it's worth, you might look into the Tracking Import module over at Creativemgroup.com. Word on the street is a forthcoming version of this module includes the edit-in-place functionality you're looking for.

Comment: many thanks. Please find my update to code in original. Next step is to get it to render. This is not working, whitepage @#$% ERROR ^&*(

Comment: Check your error logs. If you're getting a white page (HTTP status 500), then it's a PHP fatal error. Can you post the PHP error?

Comment: Error here. exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: SNH_ShipMailInvoice_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_addTrackingColumnToGrid' thrown by Layout.php(411): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('SNH_ShipMailInv...', Array and triggered by uncommenting the line    'renderer' => 'SNH_ShipMailInvoice_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_addTrackingColumnToGrid'

Comment: Currently stuck between step 2b and 2c

Comment: SNH_ShipMailInvoice sounds like a third party extension. Unless you're extending an extension or developing with this extension as a dependency, I would recommend disabling the third-party module during your development, and then adding it later. However, you might try using the `new` constructor instead of passing the block class name; that is, `'renderer' => new SNH_ShipMailInvoice_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_addTrackingColumnToGrid()` -- let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi Jona, SNH_ShipMailInvoice is my extension that Im programming. I tried NEW before, but will try agian

Comment: It would stand to reason that a class alias or class name should be set as a string, but in my experience, sometimes the render does not work unless you use the `new` keyword and instantiate a new object.